React Native Project - Built Fail due to NDK
I was working on my new react native project. It is working well and I install npm packages for react-navigation. After that I run my project it give me this error
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project 
':react-native-screens'. > [CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users\haide\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\26.1.10909125 did not have a source.properties file * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 1s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.


Can anyone tell me what the problem is here? I'm working on React Native after 5 or 6 months and don't know what this problem is.

Have you installed the package for react-native-screens?

yes, "react-native-screens": "^3.34.0"

Is there a ndkVersion variable in android > build.gradle?

Yes, ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"

Change it to ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393", it is a known issue in react-native-screens


[CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users###\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393 did not have a source.properties file.


I think neither of these NDK's are installed. This GitHub pages explains the issue and possible fixes - https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/2114

I solve this problem with the help of Thomasino73
I just install NDK form android studio.

